# Can view Sustainability site content when not logged in during private beta

Tags: bug, login, private-beta

I am currently able to view the content of the Sustainability private beta although I am not logged in.

I was invited and do have an account, but I assume this is still a bug.

I logged in this morning. But currently it appears as though I am logged out. When I came onto the MSO site it shows 2 notifications. It appears as though I am not logged in at all o the Sustainability site.

I am on an iPhone.

I have taken a screenshot withy iPhone and can share latter if requested.

Comment: Now I remember why I haven't been on SE sites for 3 months. Passive aggressiveness and fly by down votes. Think I will go back to Reddit. Anyone think I was just trying I be helpful?

Comment: It might be a bit premature to complain about passive aggressiveness and fly by down votes on SE after 1 downvote. Granted, it might have been better on their part to explain their rationale as you're only trying to help.